# Scroll Event at end of Select Dropdown in Angular 4

Tags: angular, scroll, addeventlistener

I am trying to call a Scroll Event in component class once dropdown list end is reached. SO i can load n ext set of data in dropdown as list is huge and I am only loading first 30 records on ngOnInit().

When user scrolls down, I need to fire event and update the dropdown list so it can show 30 more records now and similar for more scroll.

I tried finding solution and implemented this:

HTML:

```
<select (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)" class="custom-select">
      <option *ngFor="let record of records</option>
</select>
```

Component Class:

```
@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event) {
  console.log("Called on Scroll Event");
}
```

Still No Luck. What I am doing wrong here? Should I use Virtual Scroll or ng-select ? ngbDropDown? Can someone help me with plunker or stackblitz? Would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check when your scroll has ended.
You can do something like below

```js
@HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
onWindowScroll() {
  //In chrome and some browser scroll is given to body tag
  let pos = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
  let max = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
  // pos/max will give you the distance between scroll bottom and and bottom of screen in percentage.
  if (pos == max) {
    //Call your Method to fetch more records
  }
}
```

Also remember to import Host Listener

Comment: I need it only for Dropdown scroll, not for window scroll.

Comment: You can do something like this:-  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  ...
}    or this below:- <div (scroll)="onScroll($event)"

Comment: It works with div but not with select html element so it is not working.

Comment: It won't work on select bro.Your Contents of dropdown must be in a div..use that.Debug and get that element name and then use it